# Swift: Function syntax with closure and type alias

Tags: swift, closures, type-alias

I don't understand the syntax of the loop through the function at the end of this code snippet (from a course I'm taking). 
Is members acting as a placeholder for the array of strings that arrayClosure uses? If that is the case, I can see how name would be a placeholder for each value in that array. If not, I don't know how to read this execution of activeMembers at the end.

```
var partyMembers = ["Harrison", "Steven", "Bob the Noob"]


typealias AttackTuple = (name: String, damage: Int, rechargeable: Bool)


var sunStrike: AttackTuple = ("Rainbow Burst", 1000, false)


func levelUpAttack(baseAttack: AttackTuple) -> AttackTuple {

    let increasedAttack: AttackTuple = (baseAttack.name, baseAttack.damage + 10, true)
        return increasedAttack
    }

var poweredAttack = levelUpAttack(baseAttack: sunStrike)


func activeMembers(completion: arrayClosure) {
    completion(partyMembers)
}

//I don't understand what name is referencing here

activeMembers { (members) in
    for name in members {
        print("\(name) is active")
    }
}
```

Insight is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It’s the name of the variable that holds the current element in the iteration. In this case it is a String variable.

Comment: where is `arrayClosure` defined? Hold down command and click on `arrayClosure`

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath `arrayClosure` would have to be `typealias arrayClosure = ([Member]) -> Void`

Comment: Of course you _could_ read the Swift language guide. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

Comment: Nice recommendation @matt. Maybe just comment the link next time though. Trying promote good conduct

Comment: Thank you @noodl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
activeMembers { (members) in
    for name in members {
        print("\(name) is active")
    }
}
```

is a call to `activeMembers`(completion:)`. When fully de-sugared, it looks like this:

```
activeMembers(completion: { (members: [Member]) -> Void in
    for name in members {
        print("\(name) is active")
    }
})
```

Since you haven't given us the definition of the `arrayClosure` typealias (which should be capitalized like other type names, btw, `ArrayClosure`), I've had to assume that `members` has type `[Member]`.

The closure (the code starting between the `{ }`) is just a value, and that value is passed as an argument to the `completion` parameter of `activeMembers`. The implmentation of the `activeMembers` function is then taking the `completion` closure, and calling it. It calls it, giving the `partyMembers` value as an argument to its sole parameter.

Since `completion` is referring to your for-loop-containing closure, calling it will run the code inside your closure. The `partyMembers` argument is now the value of the `members` parameter, which is then looped over and printed.

You can better understand this by tracing through what's going on:

```
var partyMembers = ["Harrison", "Steven", "Bob the Noob"]
typealias Member = String
typealias arrayClosure = ([Member]) -> Void

func activeMembers(completion: arrayClosure) {
    print("About to call completion")
    print("The value of partyMembers is: \(partyMembers)")
    completion(partyMembers)
    print("About to return from activeMembers(completion:)")
}

print("1. About to create closure")
let closure: arrayClosure = { (members: [Member]) -> Void in
    print("4. Entered closure, about to loop over the members.")
    print("5. The value of the members parameter is: \(members)")
    for name in members {
        print("\(name) is active")
    }
    print("6. Finished looping")
    print("7. About to return from the closure")
}
print("2. Closure created")

print("3. About to call activeMembers(completion:)")
activeMembers(completion: closure)
print("8. Finished call to activeMembers(completion:)")
```

Comment: I appreciate the thorough response! I will keep coming back to this until I can digest it fully.

Comment: @AmberVictoria No problem, let me know if you have any questions